# Strange behavior when separating by loose parts

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects

I have built a huge tower of blocks by using 3 modifiers that duplicate blocks on the x, y, and z axes. I applied 1 of the modifiers and separated (by loose parts), and this is what happened: [image: after separating]

The cubes before separating:
[image: before separating]

Modifier configuration and initial cubes:
[image]

None of the cubes are touching; there is a tiny distance between them.

Comment: probably because you are using relative_offset which will be effected by the object dimension after separation, either apply all modifier or change offset type